# How to use .each jQuery to get <th> ids and set <td> attributes with each of them?

Tags: jquery, html-table

I want to be able to get the ids of each `<th>` and set them to the data attribute of each `<td>` of the table.

Before:

```
<table>
<tr>
<th id="1"><th>
<th id="2"><th>
</tr>

<tr>
<td><td>
<td><td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td><td>
<td><td>
</tr>

...

</table>
```

After:

```
<table>
<tr>
<th id="1"><th>
<th id="2"><th>
</tr>

<tr>
<td data="1"><td>
<td data="2"><td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td data="1"><td>
<td data="2"><td>
</tr>

...

</table>
```

So far, I have this jQuery :

```
 array = $('table th').map(function(){
        return this.id;
    });

    i = 0;
    $('table tr td').each(function() {

       $(this).attr('data-title', array[i]);
       i++;

    });
```

But it doesn't work at all.

Any ideas?

Comment: "Doesn't work at all" is not a useful problem statement.  Does the code run?  Does it throw errors? What about it does / doesn't work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is that `$('table tr td')` is going to return all the tds, so if you have 2 rows of 4 tds, the result is 8 tds, and 8 is larger than your th count.  You have to loop through each row.

```js
//loop over each row
$('table tr').each(function() {
  //use the index of the td in the row for the array
  $(this).find('td').each(function(index){
    $(this).attr('data-title', array[index]);
  });
});


//or as an alternative
array.each(function(index, id){
  $('table tr td:nth-child('+ (index + 1) +')').attr('data-title', id);
});
```